# Create a function to truncate text and adding "..." at the end of the text truncated. JS

Tags: javascript, text, alert

I'm new and learning JS.
As described in the title I want that the browser 'alert' the text truncated +'...', if his lenght is higher than the maxlenght. The browser doesn't do so, someone can help me please?

```js
let str = prompt('Insert Text', '');
let maxLenght = +prompt('write max length', '');

function truncate(str, maxLenght) {
  if (str.length > maxLenght) {
    return str.slice(0, (maxLenght - 1)) + '...';
  } else {
    return str
  }
}

alert(truncate());
```

Comment: Your parameters to your function are shadowing your global variables, but your parameters are undefined because you're not passing through any arguments to your function call. You need to pass them through `truncate(str, maxLenght)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variables to the function. Also you don't need to use `maxLenght - 1` because `slice` doesn't include the last index by default.

```js
let str = prompt('Insert Text', '');
let maxLenght = +prompt('write max length', '');

function truncate(str, maxLenght) {
  if (str.length > maxLenght) {
    return str.slice(0, (maxLenght)) + '...';
  } else {
    return str
  }
}

alert(truncate(str, maxLenght));
```